# PGP Encryption and Decryption in Android?

Tags: android, encryption, public-key-encryption, pgp, openpgp

I am new to PGP encryption and Decryption technique. Can anybody take a look into this how to implement.

I tried and implemented successfully by using a vendor provided that libraries. But it is supporting only for free trial with 45 days. But I need it freeware for development. Can anyone suggest me how to use it for free or any other vendor libraries available.

***Below are the links I used to implement it.***

[Vendor Site Link for libraries](https://www.didisoft.com/android-openpgp/)

[Encryption Sample](https://www.didisoft.com/android-openpgp/examples/encrypt/)